# Keep Mocha tests alongside source files

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I currently have my NodeJS source files in `src` and test suites in `test`, e.g.:

```
/src/bar/baz/foo.js
/test/bar/baz/foo.spec.js
```

This leads to awkward require statements like `var foo = require('../../../src/bar/baz/foo')`. And it's hard to see at a glance which source files are missing tests. I would like to instead keep my test suites in the same directory as the relevant source files:

```
/src/bar/baz/foo.js
/src/bar/baz/foo.spec.js
```

But now running `mocha --recursive src` causes errors as Mocha tries to run my source files as tests.

I've seen suggestions of using `find` or `gulp` to filter the file list but I find it surprising that this can't be done with plain Mocha. What's the recommended way of organising files this way?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just pass the pattern of your test files to mocha, like:

```
mocha "src/**/*.spec.js"
```

This is going to run the `.spec.js` files in all subdirectories of `src`.

Comment: So simple! The double-quotes presumably stop the shell from expanding the pattern and let Mocha's `glob` do it.